# Как проверить на отсутствие ключа, если его нет то создать ключ и присвоить значение по умолчанию

Tags: javascript

```js
let areaData = [
  {group: 3, vol: 15555},
  {group: 4, vol: 78578},
  {group: 5, vol: 5875},
  {group: 6, vol: 585896},
  {group: 7, vol: 257},
];

let verData = [];

for (let i in areaData) {

  // Если отсутствует ключ, то создать ключ и присвоить значение 0
  // Ниже условие также выдает ошибку
  // if (verData[areaData[i].group]?.vol) verData[areaData[i].group].vol = 0;

  verData[areaData[i].group] = {
    vol: verData[areaData[i].group].vol + areaData[i].vol,
  };
}

console.log(this.verData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let areaData = [
  {group: 3, vol: 15555},
  {group: 4, vol: 78578},
  {group: 5, vol: 5875},
  {group: 6, vol: 585896},
  {group: 7, vol: 257},
  {group: 7, vol: 1}
];

let verData = [];

for (let i in areaData) {
  const group = areaData[i].group;
  (verData[group] || (verData[group] = {vol: 0})).vol += areaData[i].vol;
}

console.log(verData);
```